# Language Files Don't Appear To Be Loading

Tags: cartthrob

I've just installed Cartthrob 2.5 and it looks as though the language files aren't loading properly in the admin area. Specifically the "CartThrob Price - By Member Group" and "CartThrob Price - Quantity" field types:

[image]

The language files are definitely on the server, so I'm not sure what's going on. Anyone else noticed this??

Comment: Where are the language files located on the server? Have you re uploaded them?

Comment: The language files are within the third_party/cartthrob/language/english folder, as expected. But it's simply not bringing them in. If I delete/rename the language folder on the server, it complains that it can't read the language file in, so it's definitely looking in the right place....

Comment: Sounds like it's a bug. I don't have CartThrob files to dig into here so I can only post a suggestion on what I'd do. I'd check to see if they've issued a quickfix or newer version. If not, you're going to need to track it backwards. It's probably a misspelling in the language file name... so manually check the module files to see if the spelling of the file name is correct.